# How to export component as an image on react and save locally as a file object on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image, image-processing

Is there any way to export a component render as a png and save it to the database as a file object which can be accessed by the rest of the site?

I know there's a library called `react-component-export-image`, but I want to create this as a file object which can then be used for other functions (as opposed to just being able to download to the user's machine).

in my use case, I want to save a banner with custom text and use call it in multiple places (user profile, account settings, etc.). It's sort of a one-time export that can never be changed (like an nft?).

Comment: Take a screenshot of it.

Comment: You may want to consider using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Comment: @caTS I don't think a screenshot exports it as a file object. also it seems like the quality of the screenshot is (noticeably) lower than the render. any way to fix that/any other method?